# Why is <input type="file"> box grey in IE8?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, file-io

Can anyone explain why my `input type="file"` is greyed out in IE8 but not IE7. It's still usable, but you can't actually type in the box any more.

```
<INPUT id="fil1" type="file" size="44" name="fil1" runat="server">
```

IE7:

[image: In IE7]

IE8:

[image: In IE8]

Comment: It was working fine until yesterday and now it's broken !!! I tried removing windows update from the last two days and still no go !! Freaking microsoft : If something works for 10 years, can't they think that a lot of people are actually using it !!

Comment: Why has this question been marked down. Surely it's a useful question, and clearly explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input type='file'>` is treated as a special case input field in all browsers. It looks different in pretty much every browser, and it can't easily be styled using CSS.

The reason for this is that the browsers consider it to have security issues, for example, where users may upload files without realising it. They therefore enforce a standard look and feel for it, so that the field will always be recognised for what it is. They also prevent CSS and Javascript from having access to the field so that they cannot modify the how it looks or alter the value of it.

In the case of IE8, the browser developers have decided that the only way the user should be allowed to access the field is via the file selector button. This is a concious decision by the IE developers to increase security. There's nothing you can do about it.

For the sake of curiosity, you should try seeing how `<input type='field'>` is rendered in other browsers - Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera... you'll be surprised by how different they all are in how they render this. It's probably the single most inconsitently rendered element.

Comment: Thank you. Just got to convince my moaning customers that this is a "positive change" then. They're seeing it rather differently right now :-)

Comment: @Urbycoz - See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_select - quote: "Some browsers ... no longer allow a filename to be typed directly in. This is a security measure..."

Answer (score -1):

Because the textbox is readonly; which is the expected behaviour. You can select a file using the Browse button.

Typing is not an option, since the file is on the users pc and the webpage cannot directly access those files.

Comment: Typing was an option in IE7. What if you know the full path and would rather type it for some reason? It doesn't need to access anything.